# Low Search paginate_base URL with Structure & Freebie

Tags: structure, search, low-search, pagination, freebie

When using the `paginate_base` parameter with `exp:low_search:results` (I'm also using Structure, Freebie) any time I reference the channel short_name either as {segment_1}, {freebie_1}, {channel_short_name} or even hard code the channel short name, the pagination URL has the search query in the wrong place.

Using:

```
paginate_base="{freebie_1}/{freebie_2}/{freebie_3}/{freebie_4}/{freebie_5}/{freebie_6}"
```

When the URL is:

http://domain.com/yarn/title/asc/1/brand/dmc/P1?keywords=test

the generated pagination URL is:

```
http://domain.com/yarn/?keywords=yarntitle/asc/1/brand/dmc/P2?keywords=yarn
```

But if I hardcode a non-existing channel_short_name at {segment_1} - for example: foo

`paginate_base="foo/{freebie_2}/{freebie_3}/{freebie_4}/{freebie_5}/{freebie_6}"`

the generated pagination URL path is correct! Eg:

```
http://local.tricotshop.co.uk/foo/title/asc/1/brand/dmc/P2?keywords=test
```

But if I use a standard `exp:channel:entries` loop (without the results query), the generated pagination URL is correct.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it please?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you set the Encode query setting to Yes? Does that produce correct URIs?

Comment: Yes, it produces the correct URIs - but without the encoded search query.

Comment: Care to take this to https://getsatisfaction.com/low ? I need more info...

Comment: Yep, no probs - https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/exp_low_search_results_paginate_base_url_with_structure_freebie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I was using freebie segments to dynamically add sorting and ordering parameters. Low took a look at the site and recommended that the better (and correct!) way of dynamically adding the sorting and ordering parameters in Low Search is to build the URL and include them in the query. This can be done numerous ways, but the end result looks something like:

`domain.com/channel?orderby=date&sort=desc&limit=15&custom_field=foo`

Great product, great support. Will definitely use again.